# VBA Multiple charts with empty cell condition

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I am still working on my dashboard and I ran on another problem.
So now I have two sheets one named: "Current DMB Template" and 2nd named "KPI".
In main tab there is two columns green one D8:E27 and red one G8:H27:

[image]

In KPI there are 4 tables:
[image]

Now I need a macro that will create a chart for each table from KPI in either green or red column depending on if the KPI was achieved or not.

I have written a code with conditions BUT for unknown reason the code does not recognize my `IsEmpty` condition and over puts charts one on another if they have or have not been achieved. To show you on snaps, I want this:
[image]

And my code does this:
[image]

The code is:

```
Dim embeddedchart As ChartObject

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set kpi = wb.Sheets("KPI")
Set main = wb.Sheets("Current DMB Template")

    If kpi.Range("e2").Value = "No" Then
    Set embeddedchart = main.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=Range("G9").Left, Width:=170, Top:=Range("G9").Top, Height:=100)
    embeddedchart.Chart.SetSourceData source:=kpi.Range("A2:C2")
    Else
    Set embeddedchart = main.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=Range("D9").Left, Width:=170, Top:=Range("D9").Top, Height:=100)
    embeddedchart.Chart.SetSourceData source:=kpi.Range("A2:C2")
    
    End If
    
    If kpi.Range("e5").Value = "No" Then
    Set embeddedchart = main.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=Range("G9").Left, Width:=170, Top:=Range("G9").Top, Height:=100)
    embeddedchart.Chart.SetSourceData source:=kpi.Range("A5:C5")
    Else
    Set embeddedchart = main.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=Range("D9").Left, Width:=170, Top:=Range("D9").Top, Height:=100)
    embeddedchart.Chart.SetSourceData source:=kpi.Range("A5:C5")
    
    End If
    
    If kpi.Range("e8").Value = "No" And  IsEmpty(main.Range("G9").Value) Then
    Set embeddedchart = main.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=Range("G9").Left, Width:=170, Top:=Range("G9").Top, Height:=100)
    embeddedchart.Chart.SetSourceData source:=kpi.Range("A8:C8")
    ElseIf kpi.Range("e8").Value = "No" And Not IsEmpty(main.Range("G9").Value) Then
    Set embeddedchart = main.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=Range("G16").Left, Width:=170, Top:=Range("G16").Top, Height:=100)
    embeddedchart.Chart.SetSourceData source:=kpi.Range("A8:C8")
    Else
    Set embeddedchart = main.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=Range("D9").Left, Width:=170, Top:=Range("D9").Top, Height:=100)
    embeddedchart.Chart.SetSourceData source:=kpi.Range("A8:C8")
    
    End If
    

End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*for unknown reason the code does not recognize my IsEmpty condition*

Not sure if I understand properly but charts are on a different layer than cells. I mean that even if you got a chart which top cell is G9 the cell is still empty because there is no value inside the cell itself. Try modifying your code adding something inside the cell (the graph will be over this so nothing can be seen):

Try like this:

```
Dim embeddedchart As ChartObject
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set kpi = wb.Sheets("KPI")
Set main = wb.Sheets("Current DMB Template")

If kpi.Range("e2").Value = "No" Then
    Set embeddedchart = main.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=Range("G9").Left, Width:=170, Top:=Range("G9").Top, Height:=100)
Else
    Set embeddedchart = main.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=Range("D9").Left, Width:=170, Top:=Range("D9").Top, Height:=100)
End If

embeddedchart.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=kpi.Range("A2:C2")

If kpi.Range("e5").Value = "No" Then
    Set embeddedchart = main.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=Range("G9").Left, Width:=170, Top:=Range("G9").Top, Height:=100)
    main.Range("G9").Value = " " 'just to force it no empty
Else
    Set embeddedchart = main.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=Range("D9").Left, Width:=170, Top:=Range("D9").Top, Height:=100)
End If

embeddedchart.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=kpi.Range("A5:C5")

If kpi.Range("e8").Value = "No" And IsEmpty(main.Range("G9").Value) Then
    Set embeddedchart = main.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=Range("G9").Left, Width:=170, Top:=Range("G9").Top, Height:=100)
ElseIf kpi.Range("e8").Value = "No" And Not IsEmpty(main.Range("G9").Value) Then
    Set embeddedchart = main.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=Range("G16").Left, Width:=170, Top:=Range("G16").Top, Height:=100)
Else
    Set embeddedchart = main.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=Range("D9").Left, Width:=170, Top:=Range("D9").Top, Height:=100)
End If

embeddedchart.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=kpi.Range("A8:C8")

End Sub
```

**UPDATE**: Don't use `IsEmtpy` to check where to draw. Looking at your code, looks like if `kpi.Range("e2").Value = "No"` you always graph at column G, else you graph at column D.

Use that as a factor to draw. I tried to replicate your data in a similar way with a much simpler code. Hope this can help you out. Notice that depending of where the values of E are no or yes the graphs are somewhere else

Fake KPI worksheet

[image]

With all E values as no i get this:

[image]

With all E values different than `no` i get this:

[image]

If I mix yes and no:

[image]

Notice the output is not exactly as yours because my Excel version is different, but this code it's a good approach.

The code:

```
Sub test()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim main As Worksheet
Dim kpi As Worksheet

Dim embeddedchart As ChartObject
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set main = wb.Sheets("Current DMB Template")
Set kpi = wb.Sheets("KPI")

Dim TotalGraphsD As Byte 'will store how many graphs in D
Dim TotalGraphsG As Byte ' will store how many graphs in G
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim ThisColumn As String


For i = 2 To 8 Step 3 'loop trough 2-8 in breaks of 3-> 2,5,8
    ThisColumn = IIf(kpi.Range("E" & i).Value = "no", "G", "D") 'which column will be the graph
    j = 9 + (7 * IIf(ThisColumn = "G", TotalGraphsG, TotalGraphsD))  'which row will be the graph, first in row 9 in steps of 7 so, first in row 9, second row 16, third row 23 and so on...
    Set embeddedchart = main.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=Range(ThisColumn & j).Left, Width:=170, Top:=Range(ThisColumn & j).Top, Height:=100)
    embeddedchart.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=kpi.Range("A" & i & ":C" & i)
    If ThisColumn = "G" Then TotalGraphsG = TotalGraphsG + 1 Else TotalGraphsD = TotalGraphsD + 1
Next i


End Sub
```

The line `For i = 2 To 8`  wll handle the series to be drawn so if you got many more each 3 rows at range A:C you can handle from here. Example:

[image]

Output (notice how the yes and no values are related to where the graphs are drawn). Also in this code I've used `For i = 2 To 26`

[image]

Uploaded a sample to Gdrive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Qhau1PcXssZ3RbJTNzhKhwDAelUaZusv/view?usp=share_link

Comment: Hey @Foxfire you got it right! I also though that that could be a problem and I was hoping that there would be another solution, because as this Dashboard would be updated daily, the data in the tables would change again, and that means that I would have to add another line to the code which would delete the "invisible" value before populating data again, but yes your solution is working. The other option that I have is simply for each of the tables to have chart in different row. I will discuss it on meeting today.

Comment: @Kris_Toor Please, check updated answer. Maybe the update can be a starting point for your needs.

Comment: YOU ARE THE BEST! It worked. Initially as it was early morning I made some mistakes and I thought it didn't work (thus my earlier comments under this thread that I deleted) but I noticed my errors and all is fine now. Your code is far more simple and easier. Many thx for that!

Comment: Hello @Foxfire, I have one more issue with those charts. They appear and everything works beautifully, but now there appears a legend that shows 2 positions: Series 1 and Series 2, how can I change it for Realization and Target respectively? I have watched hundreds of videos and read fora but the way that they show does not work here, as chartobject does not have property series? Can we alter somehow your code so that it will take into consideration also row A1 where the name of series could be taken from?

Comment: @Kris_Toor Probably yes, but you should open a new question with this issue, different than your original question, so everything keeps properly organized. The actual answer resolves your previous problem and now you are facing a new one, so please open a new question.

Comment: Yes, of course, I have already posted new question, thank you!